# Is SFP+ backwards compatible with SFP?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus-5k, sfp, transceiver

Can I stick an SFP transceiver module in a SFP+ port in a Cisco Nexus 5K for example if I need to connect a fast ethernet switch with a 1 Gbps SFP uplink port? I saw this Nexus's ports are 1/10 Gbps.

Does it depend on a switch module or is there a general rule, that they should be compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT*:

GigabitEthernet SFP transceivers are supported in 1/10G SFP+ Nexus 5k slots.  Please see the [Nexus 5k Datasheet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-5000-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-618603.html) (see Table 2) for details.

*Original Answer*:
<strike>No [FastEthernet SFP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/interfaces-modules/fast-ethernet-sfp-modules/index.html)s are listed in the [Nexus 5k Datasheet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-5000-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-618603.html) (see Table 2); as such, you're out of luck.  FastEthernet SFPs are not supported on the Nexus 5k; however, many FastEthernet switches have GigabitEthernet uplinks.  If that FE switch has a GE uplink, then use that GE port on the FE switch.</strike>

The old GBIC transceiver format was pretty generic and you could ignore branding on them. SFPs are a different animal, vendors qualify individual part numbers for support; you can even see different transceiver part number support between different switches from the same vendor.

Comment: Sorry, I mean FastEthernet switch With a GigabitEthernet SFP uplinks.

Comment: What part number is your Nexus?  Which specific port are you trying to plug into?

Comment: I am not plugging atm. but I'm just researching if I can find an SFP transceiver (for 1Gbps connectivity) which is compatible with N5K's SFP+ ports. Thank you!